# Favicon does not showup

Tags: favicon

I activated the All in one Favicon and then uploaded my Favicon in the settings but it does not show up in any browser (my under construction site: http://www.kheemh.com/).

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I do see your favicon

Comment: I see the favicon as well but when I looked 20 minutes ago or so I did not see it, nor did I see any tags in the source that reference the favicon (which are present now)

Comment: Was this a simple caching issue or did you do something else to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delete de cache of your browser

Comment: If this answer is correct, perhaps you could mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: It was apparently caching issue.

Comment: I was expecting to see the favicon in the url bar but it only appears on the tab.
Thanks again to all.
B